# controlsDescendantBindings (stopBinding) inside block with "with" not works when main element is initially hidden

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have very complex markup on the page. So in some region of it I need main model,
to show its child object when clicking on some element. Child object is also complex object so to show it one property
I use custom control with separate applyBinding call. Some properties of child are simple properties so I directly show them.
Here is simplified markup of this part:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
     return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
   }
};

<div id="shell" data-bind="with:details, visible:isVisible">
   <h2 data-bind="text: $root.header"></h2>
   <div data-bind="stopBinding: true" style="block;clear:both">
      <div id="profile">
        first name:<input data-bind="value: first" />
        last name:<input data-bind="value: last" />
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When isVisible is initially true- all works as expected. When it is set to true somewhere later - inner binding not works. Any ideas why this could happen?
Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yauhen/NNMLh/

Answer (score 4):

The issue that you are seeing is related to the fact that all bindings for a single element are fired [together](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/06/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-3-all-bindings.html).  This means that when you change `isVisible`, you are triggering both the `visible` binding and the `with` binding.  When the `with` binding is triggered, it will replace its children with its "template" (original child elements) and rebind.

In your case, a fix would be to put those bindings on separate elements. Perhaps add an additional "wrapper" div inside that has the `visible` binding like:

```
<div data-bind="with: details">
   <div data-bind="visible: $parent.isVisible">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I know about this solution. But this causes fake empty div when no details are shown (I believe this will not affect other markup) and also remembering why this fake div is used. I believe in next 3rd versions knockout will be more intelligent. I have other strange issues with inner binding in IE8 (I think also related with visible) but I could not create good small example for them in jsfiddle

Comment: If having an extra div does not work in your scenario, then you could use a containerless `with` binding (this does not work for `visible`). So, it would be like `<!-- ko with: details -->` and closed with `<!-- /ko -->`.  The extra `div` though has `display: none` when visible is false, so it is hidden anyways.  When KO 3.0 is releasted, bindings on the same element will be isolated, so your original scenario would work. It will be a bit before KO 3.0 is ready to go though.

Comment: If you must have this now, then here is a way to create a custom binding that applies the `visible` binding in a way that it is isolated from the other bindings on that element. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/bTYS9/.  Note that this would only work when passing an observable directly like `isVisible` and not if accessing observables in the binding string like `!isVisible()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves all this sample issues. I finally could produce IE8 sample specific: http://jsfiddle.net/yauhen/nzhbM/show not sure it is related with the same problem. Changing with position so it is just over first div solve problem. But in real page child is inside very long form so I it will be annoying to create several with section just to leave child outside of any with. may be you have any ideas?

Comment: seem to me calling applyBindings for nested after parent fix issue. But all this is kind of tricks :(